# Restart Service on Remote System Batch

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

Just having trouble with a batch and need some clarification on 'IF', 'ELSE' and 'GOTO'

```
@echo off

sc \\RemoteServer stop "My_Service"

:query
sc \\RemoteServer query "My_Service"

if %state% == 1 goto start # state =1 indicates service is stopped
else goto query

:start
sc \\RemoteServer start "My_Service"
```

So, what I want to happen, is for the service to be stopped, the batch to query the state of the service, and depending on the state, proceed to the next step. This is necessary, as the service takes quite a white to stop. If the service is stuck in `3 STOP_PENDING` then the `sc start` will fail.

Can someone explain why my GOTO is failing, or possibly offer better methodology?

TNA

Answer (score 0):

Using an if statement in batch usually follows this format:

```
if %state%==1 (
   goto start
) ELSE (
   goto query
)
```

There's no reason the cmd interpreter associates the ELSE with the IF othwerise.

Also, comments in batch on their own line, with a `REM` or specially-interpreted `::` (some kind of null line label or something if I recall correctly).

```
REM this is a valid comment
:: this too, but be careful using these inside blocks of any kind... so stick to REM
```

Comment: Also, be careful of the closing parenthesis. Sometimes, when it's by itself as in the example given by Wally, the command before it will throw an error. A better practice is to put the closing parenthesis right after the `goto query` as such: `goto query)` Using an editor like Notepad++, which has syntax highlighting, also helps to troubleshoot blocks in batch scripts. And whatever you do, don't use an apostrophe as a comment delimiter. The only valid comments in batch scripts are `REM` and `::`

Comment: Oh, I got that wrong? Fixed.